# PhoneNumberUtil returns missing or invalid default region on a few devices

Tags: android

I parse phone numbers from `String` representation via `com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil`> I faced with the issue

> INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE. Missing or invalid default region
>   :

- phone number on Lollipop is parsed successfully and on KitKat (at least on some devices) the same phone number is parsed with `NumberParseException`

It gives me a thought the issue can be in versions of library.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you, it helps me handle this case

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You should use Android's [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)  Please have a look at the link, it's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if the International Phone Code can't be assumed

```
PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(mobileNumber, "US");
```

To void that better have a default country code, or if not possible, ask the user to input this information as well